# Simplify $(1-x)^3+2y^3-3(1-x)y^2=0$ to $-(x - 2 y - 1) (x + y - 1)^2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, cubics

How to simplify $(1-x)^3+2y^3-3(1-x)y^2=0$?

I tried it and the result I'm aiming for is $$-(x - 2 y - 1) (x + y - 1)^2 = 0.$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$(1-x)^3+2y^3-3(1-x)y^2=0$$
$$\underbrace{(1-x)^3-(1-x)y^2}+\underbrace{2y^3-2(1-x)y^2}=0$$
$$(1-x)((1-x)^2-y^2)+2y^2(y-1+x)=0$$
$$(1-x)((1-x+y)(1-x-y))+2y^2(x+y-1)=0$$
$$-(1-x)(x+y-1)(1-x+y)+2y^2(x+y-1)=0$$
$$-(x+y-1)((1-x)^2+y-xy-2y^2)=0$$
$$-(x+y-1)(\underbrace{(1-x)^2-y^2}+\underbrace{y-xy-y^2})=0$$
$$-(x+y-1)((1-x-y)(1-x+y)+y(1-x-y))=0$$
$$-(x+y-1)(1-x-y)(1-x+y+y)=0$$
$$(x+y-1)(x+y-1)(1-x+2y)=0$$
$$-(x-2y-1)(x+y-1)^2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$
\begin{align*}
(1-x)^3+2y^3-3(1-x)y^2& =(1-x)^3\color{red}{-y^3+3y^3}-3(1-x)y^2\\
&=\color{blue}{(1-x)^3}-\color{blue}{y^3}+3y^2(y-1+x)\\
&=(1-x-y)[(1-x)^2+(1-x)y+y^2]-3y^2(1-x-y)\\
&=(1-x-y)\left[(1-x)^2+(1-x)y-2y^2\right]\\
&=(1-x-y)\left[(1-x)^2-\color{red}{y^2}+(1-x)y-\color{red}{y^2}\right]\\
&=(1-x-y)\left[(1-x-y)(1-x+y)+y\{(1-x)-y\}\right]\\
&=(1-x-y)^2(1-x+2y)\\
\end{align*}